# Blocked frame error when signing in with gplus implemented with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus

I am implementing googleplus signin using angularjs, and occasionally when i try to signin, i get a message in the browser console saying;

```
Error: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Object.stringify (native)
at oa (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:14:128)
at e.defaults.transformRequest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:63:136)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:62:337
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:7:274)
at mc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:62:319)
at f (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:65:102)
at w (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:92:5)
at w (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:92:5) angular.js:9383
```

(anonymous function) angular.js:9383

It doesn't happen all the time and it's really frustrating, since i don't know what's causing it. I will be glad for any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer
Apparently when you try to send the entire authResult object is when the error is thrown
This is because the authResult object contains a reference to the G+ auth window.

Also the reason (i think) it worked sometimes was because if the send operation starts before the window is fully destroyed (in a manner of speaking), which seems to happen a lot, then this error is seen, otherwise, it works. (I can't say i'm very certain of this though)

However, the solution is simply to call this line of code;

```
authResult['g-oauth-window'] = "";
```

This will delete the reference to the window object so that the authResult can be safely sent to the server.

Cheers!

Comment: This is the right answer! Thank you thank you! Saved me a life time of headache!

Comment: welcome @MohamedElMahallawy, glad you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cookie policy to none. I had the same issue and this solution worked for me. Still looking into the reason why

Comment: Try visiting this link [link](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/aws-js-sdk.html) and see how the sign in button was implemented. see plunkr below [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) for how you would go about it. Do not forget to include the javascript origin at the developer console since i couldnt get it to work with plunkr but it works generally when running it on a registered origin.